# About Morphia Version (optimistic lock)

Tags: mongodb, redis, morphia

As our project has a very high frequency of reading and writing data from MongoDB, we decide to load some of data to Redis to reduce requests to write/read Mongo.

We stored entity's id for redis-key, entity's serialized JSON string for redis-value. The data stored in Redis like this:

```
key   :  "id_18035138" 
value :  "{
           "id":"...",
           ...,
           "version":1
          }
```

After stored these data, when we need to update data, we first parse the JSON string to entity, then update properties, then refresh the data in Redis. So the data in Redis will be the latest data.

When we need to save Redis data to MongoDB, we first parse the JSON string to entity ,then use Morphia DAO to save entity, but we faced this exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: Entity of class com.lk.game.entities.User (id='...',version='1') was concurrently updated.
```

I know this must be optimistic lock's problem. How could we solve this concurrent exception?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

> How could we solve this concurrent exception?

Not writing concurrently... Obviously you have at least two actors writing back the same document in parallel.

I don't think it's possible to know how or why this is happening in your system with the information you've given.

Maybe you could also change the architecture?

- Can you handle the load with MongoDB on its own? More hardware, better sharding, more tuning,... — this won't solve the concurrency issue in generell, but you might be able to shorten the collision window.
- Can you use Redis on its own? At least for some operations it seems to be sufficient to read the data from Redis.
- Do you need optimistic versioning or would "last-write-wins" work as well?
- Maybe MongoDB is just the wrong database for this task and you could replace MongoDB+Redis with CouchBase (built-in memcached and "better" sharding to the consistent ring hashing)

Comment: Maybe the current architecture is not smart enough LOL. I'll find some information about CouchBase. Really appreciate!

Comment: IMHO writing the same data to 2 databases in parallel just calls for trouble. And what's the number of inserts/updates you're trying to do? Must be huge, if you can't get it done with a properly sized and configured MongoDB cluster

Comment: @ZacharyTang The current architecture is smart enough. Your project is not.